# Magento 2: Data printed in Controller but display null in observer

Tags: event-observer, custom

Controller file

```
$collection = $this->investmentFactory->create()->load($id);
        $collection->getData();

        // echo '<pre/>';
        // print_r($collection->getData());
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('trigger_order_place',['collection', $collection]);
        exit;
```

In this observer file data is null

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        var_dump($collection);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you must pass key => value and you pass like two array items. Here is from core code.

```
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'sales_order_payment_capture',
            ['payment' => $payment, 'invoice' => $invoice]
        );
```

Try changing to

`$this->eventManager->dispatch('trigger_order_place',['collection' => $collection]);`

Comment: I agree with this.